# idris-mode – Buffer *idris-repl* has no process

Tags: emacs, idris

I'm trying to get idris-mode to work. I am using HEAD from both [idris-dev](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev) and [idris-mode](https://github.com/idris-hackers/idris-mode). Whenever I execute C-l (idris-load-file) I get this error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "make client process failed" "connection refused" :name "Idris Ideslave" :buffer "*idris-connection*" :host "127.0.0.1" :service 0 :nowait nil)
  make-network-process(:name "Idris Ideslave" :buffer "*idris-connection*" :host "127.0.0.1" :service 0 :nowait nil)
  open-network-stream("Idris Ideslave" "*idris-connection*" "127.0.0.1" 0)
  (setq idris-connection (open-network-stream "Idris Ideslave" (idris-buffer-name :connection) "127.0.0.1" port))
  .............snipped
```

Whenever I try M-x idris-repl it states `Buffer *idris-repl* has no process`.

The result from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833958/idris-mode-buffer-has-no-process) thread was to update the projects from git. However I'm using the most up-to-date versions from each project.

edit: running `make` also fails, but that's probably a different issue. If I manually checkout `0.9.16`, `make` will pass but the same issue above persists.

edit: I do not have this installed locally, I am running it out of a cabal sandbox. In `idris-settings.el` I changed `idris-interpreter-path` to the full path of idris. Also, when I run idris outside of emacs I get errors about not finding prelude or builtins. If I add -i path/to/idris/libs/prelude then everything works. But adding "-i path/to/idris/libs/prelude" to `idris-interpreter-flags` in `idris-settings.el` does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've *sort of* solved this. For `idris-interpreter-flags` you must give each actual argument as a separate string (which is common, I should have known). So, if I set `idris-interpreter-flags` to `'("-i" "/path/to/idris/libs/prelude")` then all is good. So I have to add the path for each of the libraries' directories that idris comes with.

How does this work? Is this normal to require? Is it because I'm not running this as a true cabal installed package that it doesn't pick up on the libraries?

Comment: Yes, if it's not a cabal installation then it won't be looking in the right place. I recently added a `IDRIS_LIBRARY_PATH` flag to tell it where to find libraries - you might be able to use that.